# Hoare Quicksort Algorithm Not Working properly

Tags: javascript, sorting

So with an array

```
[6, 3, 8, 7, 2, 5, -9, 1, 4, 10]
```

using Hoare's partition Algorithm I expect

```
[-9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10]
```

But the algorithm from my code gives me

```
[4, 3, 8, 7, 2, 5, -9, 1, 6, 10]
```

i'm following this algorithm verbatim basically

```
algorithm quicksort(A, lo, hi) is
    if lo < hi then
        p := partition(A, lo, hi)
        quicksort(A, lo, p)
        quicksort(A, p + 1, hi)

algorithm partition(A, lo, hi) is
    pivot := A[(lo + hi) / 2]
    i := lo - 1
    j := hi + 1
    loop forever
        do
            i := i + 1
        while A[i] < pivot

        do
            j := j - 1
        while A[j] > pivot

        if i >= j then
            return j

        swap A[i] with A[j]
```

But my code doesn't seem to produce the correct answer

```js
const arr = [6, 3, 8, 7, 2, 5, -9, 1, 4, 10]
const mid = (a, b) => (a + b) / 2

function partition(A, lo, hi) {
  const midpoint = mid(lo, hi)
  const pivot = A[midpoint]
  let i = lo - 1
  let j = hi + 1
  do {
    i += 1
  } while (A[i] < pivot)
  do {
    j -= 1
  } while (A[j] > pivot)
  if (i < j) {
    const A_i = A[i]
    A[i] = A[j]
    A[j] = A_i
  } else {
    return j
  }
}

function quicksort(A, lo, hi) {
  if (lo < hi) {
    const p = partition(A, lo, hi)

    quicksort(A, lo, p - 1)
    quicksort(A, p + 1, hi)
  }
  return A
}
quicksort(arr, 0, arr.length - 1)

console.log(arr)
console.log('[-9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10]' === JSON.stringify(arr))
```

Answer (score 2):

Some issues: you're missing the `loop forever` logic, so insert a `while(true)` before the `do {` blocks:

```
while (true) {
  do {
    i += 1
  } while (A[i] < pivot)
  do {
    // ...
```

Also, the psuedocode says to

```
quicksort(A, lo, p)
quicksort(A, p + 1, hi)
```

but you have

```
quicksort(A, lo, p - 1)
quicksort(A, p + 1, hi)
```

So, remove the `- 1`.

Another problem missing from the psuedocode is that

```
pivot := A[(lo + hi) / 2]
```

should actually be

```
pivot := A[floor((lo + hi) / 2)]
```

else `pivot` may not be an integer, and the code won't work.

Fix those issues, and the code works:

```js
function quicksort(A, lo, hi) {
  if (lo < hi) {
    const p = partition(A, lo, hi)
    quicksort(A, lo, p) // <---------------
    quicksort(A, p + 1, hi)
  }
}

function partition(A, lo, hi) {
  const pivot = A[Math.floor((lo + hi) / 2)];  // <---------------
  let i = lo - 1
  let j = hi + 1
  while (true) { // <---------------
    do {
      i += 1
    } while (A[i] < pivot)
    do {
      j -= 1
    } while (A[j] > pivot)
    if (i >= j) {
      return j;
    }
    [A[i], A[j]] = [A[j], A[i]]; // <---- easier syntax
  }
}

const arr = [6, 3, 8, 7, 2, 5, -9, 1, 4, 10]
quicksort(arr, 0, arr.length - 1)
console.log(arr)
console.log('[-9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10]' === JSON.stringify(arr))  // <---------------
```

(note that `JSON.stringify` does not result in spaces between array items)

Comment: What happens to this part: `pivot := A[(lo + hi) / 2]`, since you only using: `const midpoint = mid(lo, hi); const pivot = midpoint;` but you never access `A[midpoint]`. I will also change `const mid = (a, b) => (a + b) / 2` to `const mid = (a, b) => Math.floor((a + b) / 2);`. Try changing element `5` to `25` on the array...

Comment: Thanks, yep, looks like the `floor` part is essential, but was missing from the original psuedocode

Comment: You are welcome, it is nice that you manage to see all other errors, I only watched this one I have mentioned and the `p - 1` thing. Now, I can upvote!